# Is this a valid way to find if a number is NaN?

Tags: javascript, nan

Is this a valid way to check if a number in JS is NaN?

```
var a = 0/0;
var yesNan = (typeof a === "number") && (a.toString() === "NaN");
```

I know the following way:

```
var yesNan = (a !== a);
```

but, just wondering if the other way is ok too.

Comment: Use Number.isNaN()

Comment: Other then the general inefficiency I don't see anything invalid about it. I would use `a !== a`, `Number.isNaN`, or `isNaN` though.

Comment: Technically `Number.prototype.toString()` could be replaced with something that would break things. That said, we can't possibly check for everything that could be ruined by bad code, so if you do what you should and guard your JS environment against bad code, then in practice that would seem to work.

Comment: ...it seems that the `+` operator is unaffected by a corrupted `.toString()`, so you could use `(a + "") === "NaN"` instead.